# Send Dropzonejs file with jQuery AJAX POST request on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dropzone.js, dropzone

I have attachment form with dropzonejs file upload and note field and need to send those both fields data to my server on jQuery AJAX form submit.

Attachment HTML Form code

```
<form id="addAttachmentForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="companyAttachment box__input dz-clickable"
    </div>
    <textarea class="form-control resizeNone" name="Note" placeholder="Your note here" rows="5"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-Attachment" id="add-attachment">ADD ATTACHMENT</button>
</div>
```

JS Code

```
$(document).on('submit', '#addAttachmentForm',function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/attachment/store',
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        beforeSend: function () {
        },
        success: function(response)
        {
            // contactDropzone.processQueue();
        },
        error: function (data) {
        }
    });});

Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var contactDropzone = $('.companyAttachment').dropzone({
   url: null,
   paramName: 'file',
   addRemoveLinks: true,
   maxFiles: 1,
   autoProcessQueue: false,
   maxFilesize: 2,
   acceptedFiles: 'image/*,application/pdf',
   init: function(){
       this.on("addedfile", function(file, data) {
       });
   }});
```

I set the default value of autoProcessQueue is false, but I'm confused about when I need to call **contactDropzone.processQueue()** method to work for AJAX form submission? or please suggest me any other better ways to POST attachment and note fields data on jQuery AJAX form submission.

Comment: [This answer might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46728205/dropzone-submit-button-on-upload/46732882#46732882).

Comment: Thanks @Don'tPanic for your sharing this resolve my problem when I have one dropzonejs object but I have another scenario with multiple dropzonejs object like image upload and document upload. so, how I need to achive this with single asyn request?

Comment: Happy to help.  If the linked answer helped, please upvote it. If you have a new question, either edit this question with your new details or post a new question.